# Using DirectoryInfo to access a network drive

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi

I'm creating an application on the Raspberry Pi with c# and mono. When it uses DirectoryInfo and sets it to the network path it adds home/pi/ in front of the path. How can I prevent this?

```
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"//192.168.1.13/Volume_2/Folder");

        Console.Write("File: " + di.FullName+ ": ");
        Console.WriteLine(di.Exists);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe what you are trying to do will work that way.
The reason is that the SMB connection would normally me managed the the operating system and not C# specifically.  Also in windows it would try to authenticate to the remote server as the user which the process is running under. On Linux that would be a local user not a domain user.

I believe the easier solution would be to map the network drive within the Linux operating system then use the network share via it's mounted path.

Obviously it could vary slightly depending on what version of Linux you are using but you are most likely using Debian Wheezy which should be very similar to the article below since Ubuntu is based on Debian.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently